# Find the value of largest probability (normal distribution)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have finished a, b and c part and I have let X be the number of heads and X~Binomial(87,0.5). Also, let Y be the number of heads. Y~Normal(np,npq)
Y~Normal(43.5,21.75), but I don't really know the way to find the number of heads which have the largest probability based on the Normal approximation in part d?

Suppose we flip a coin 87 times.
Assume that the coin is fair.

a)  Compute the probability of obtaining 53 heads.

b)  Verify if the Rule of Five is satisfied? Compute the probability of obtaining
53 heads based on Normal approximation. Is the answer close to part a)?

c)  Compute the probability of obtaining at least 53 heads based on the
Normal approximation.

d)  Find the number of heads which have the largest probability based on the Normal approximation

Comment: The probability of getting $h$ heads is $${87\choose h} (0.5)^{87} $$ The binomial coefficient is maximized when $h$ is halfway in between. In this case, this will be $h=43$ or $h=44$.

Comment: The normal approximation will be maximised at the mean/median/mode, i.e. at $43.5$

Comment: What is the *Rule of Five* here?  I though it was that there was a probability $0.9375$ that the range of five samples would cover the median of a (continuous) distribution

Comment: As I think X~Binomial(87,0.5), the rule of five is npq so that is 21.75. sorry I don't really understand your second sentence after "what is the Rule of Five?" @Henry

Comment: I think this is about binomial but not base on normal approximation? @Tavish

Comment: $npq$ is the variance of a binomial distribution, which is what led to your $21.75$.  Why do you call it "rule of five"?

Comment: @cooky Yes. ${}{}$

Comment: isn't rule of five mean that when npq greater or equal to 5, N(np, npq) will be a good approximation to binomial (n,p)? so i wrote down what I had calculated for npq for your reference. @Henry

Comment: how about base on normal approximation? I don't know the way to do it. @Tavish

Comment: @cooky For large number of trials, the binomial distribution can be approximated as a normal distribution. Write the pdf for the corresponding normal distribution, then see where it is maximized.